# number formatting not working properly,while generating excel report from xsl?

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

i am converting xsl to excel report . i am not able to render integers as integers with decimal point. Eventhough i use format-number function in xsl. but when i use both 
thousand and decimal separator only the numbers with digits greater than 3 are rendered with decimal points...
Example

700 rendered as 700 itself but i want in excel as 700.00
1700 rendered as 1,700.00 when i use comma as thousand separator but when
i use only decimal separator 1700 rendered as 1700 itself...
please help me with valuable answers..

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  It will be easier to help you if you show us what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

See the specification for the [`format-number`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#function-format-number) function. The pattern string uses the syntax specified by the JDK 1.1 DecimalFormat class (See the [corresponding documentation for JDK 1.4.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html)).

In particular, `0` is a digit, `#` is a digit, omitted if zero, while `,` is the grouping (thousands) separator, and `.`  is the decimal separator.

Seems like you need `#,###.00`. Some examples:

```
format-number(700, '#,###.00')
```

> 700.00

```
format-number(1700, '#,###.00')
```

> 1,700.00

```
format-number(1700000, '#,###.00')
```

> 1,700,000.00

Comment: format-number(1700, '#,###.00') is working for numbers with digits greater than 3. when i generate pdf report it is working properly but in excel report it is not working i think there some issue while converting to excel report.

Comment: i have tried all these formats no way it is not working i am unable to track the exact issue. thanks for ur answer.

Comment: @user2156194, if you provide more information about how you are converting the output to an "excel report", perhaps someone is able to help.